# Show labels with dynamic sizes like a table without overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, uistoryboard

I am fairly new to iOS development. I am trying to create this layout:

[image: screen]

The problem is my labels are overlapping with each other because they have dynamic sizes. A label can be very long and short. This is how it looks in my attempt.

[image: screen]

As you can see, in the last field, the value is too long so it goes over the first label.

How can I fix this ?

Edit: This is actually a UITableViewCell and it is in a UITableView. I create this in storyboard. This is a prototype cell.

Comment: `I am trying to create this layout in Swift` Does it mean you're doing the autolayout work by code? You should show your existing constraints (use the [edit] button to improve your question). Thanks.

Comment: This is actually a UITableViewCell and it is in a UITableView. I create this in storyboard. This is a prototype cell if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you post your autolayout constraints? That would help us. Also, double check that your labels have `numberOfLines` set to 0 so they can span multiple lines.

Comment: @EricD I think he would like to say he is writing his code using Swift. He is new to Swift so the first tutorials you follow teach you how to use the storyboard. You don't start doing everything programatically. It's my guess.

Comment: @Ragnar Ok but we shouldn't have to *guess*. There's even a close-vote reason for that ("Unclear what you're asking"). :) I'm removing this part from OP's question, so no more confusion for now, let's see how it goes.

Comment: When I first read "I'm new to..." for me that's a way to say "Don't hit my if it's a dumb question". I had trouble to post my first questions on SO because I was new (i'm still new to swift) and I may don't use the right vocabulary and also english isn't my mother-tongue so sometime I'm not confortable with how to ask. It's really frustrating when you get bash because you are not confidente enough with how to ask something but got a real problem to solve. So when I read "I'm new to..." I made myself an effort ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your textField should have the parameter "line" as 0 as follow:
[image: Demo]

or programmatically

```
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
[...]
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        text.numberOfLines = 0
}
```

This allow your textField to use an unlimited number of lines.
After that you have to play with autolayout to set constraint between your field.